# Find 2nd and 3rd highest number Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am busy creating a podium type screen which will identify which person has the highest score and then place them into their relative positions.

Example: Given this Table:

```
+-------+-------+
| name  | score |
+-------+-------+
| Mike  |     3 |
| Kevin |    14 |
| John  |     6 |
+-------+-------+
```

Kevin would be the winner with John being second and Mike 3rd.

How would I get to this conclusion using Jquery? I have managed to trawl the internet and find out who has the highest score and then get his / her name. But I am now stuck on finding out who is 2nd and who comes third.

This is what I have so far:

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {

        var max = 0;
        var name;
        $('#HoldingPodiumData, .score').each(function()
        {
           $this = parseFloat( $(this).html() );
           if ($this > max)
           {
               max = $this;
               //name = $('.names').html();
               name = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').html()
           }


        });
        alert(max);
        alert(name);
        $("#winner").html(name);

    });
```

Could anyone help me in the right direction please? I have created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/97Gbg/2/) of what I have achieved thus far

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Array.sort() could help you...

Comment: This is simply a sorting problem. Place the elements you need into an array then sort them in descending order: `array[0] -> first` , `array[1] -> second`, `...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I would do in your case:

```
var max = 0;
var names = [];
$('#HoldingPodiumData tr:gt(0)').each(function()
{
    if ($(this).find(".score").length > 0)
    {
        names.push({
            score: parseFloat($(this).find(".score").html()),
            name: $(this).find(".names").html()
        });
    }
});

names = names.sort(function(a, b)
{
    return b.score - a.score;
});

$("#winner").html(names[0].name);
$("#second").html(names[1].name);
$("#third").html(names[2].name);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97Gbg/3/). Explanation:

1. First of all I have changed the selector to get all `tr`, skipping the first;
2. Then inside the loop I verirify if the `tr` has a `.score` child element;
3. If yes, I add it to the array of results called `names`;
4. Then I sort that array in desc order.

This is not the best way, I think, but it doesn't changes so much your code. The trick here is the [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function, you should look at it.

Comment: I like this one because I am still learning Jquery and I understand this one. Thank you man.

Comment: @Mike nice! Glad to help.

Comment: This is a good solution. The only thing to keep in mind is that the larger the table of players gets, the less efficient this will be. `sort` operates worse than a single pass of the array as in my solution. But for small datasets, this works great.

Comment: @LukeWillis sure. Thats why I warned that "its not the best way". Actually, I didn't even read data from a table nor using jQuery for it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the section where you set `max` to the new first place. Instead, keep an array of length 3 and *shift* everyone down when you find someone better than the current first place.

You can maintain the scores along side the names by keeping an additional array of the names.

```
if ($this > scores[0])
{
    scores[2] = scores[1];
    scores[1] = scores[0];
    scores[0] = $this;

    names[2] = names[1];
    names[1] = names[0];
    names[0] = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').html();
}
```

Once the code has completed, your first place winner will be held in `scores[0]`, second place will be in `scores[1]`, and third will be in `scores[2]`.

---

As an alternative to keeping two separate arrays, you could define an object with name and score properties.

Answer (score -1):

```
var scoresSorted = $('.score').map(function () { return +$(this).text(); }).get().sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
$('#winner').text( $('td:contains('+scoresSorted[0]+')').prev().text() )
$('#second').text( scoresSorted[1] )
$('#third').text( scoresSorted[2] )
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/97Gbg/5/)**

The first line gathers the values, places them in an array, and sorts them. The second line uses the first value of the array (the highest) to find the matching name. The last two lines get the second and third place values from the array (index 1 and 2).